# An incidence matrix of all subsets

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have a list manipulation problem as follows.

Suppose I have a list $L=\{1,2,3\}$.

All nonempty subsets of $L$ is $SL=\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\},\{1,2,3\}\}$.

Now I want to construct an incidence matrix of $SL$ as follows

```
{{1},{2},{3},{1,2},{1,3},{2,3},{1,2,3}} (*This is SL.*)
mat=
{{1,  0,  0,  0,0,  0,0,  0,0,  0,0,0},
 {0,  1,  0,  0,0,  0,0,  0,0,  0,0,0},
 {0,  0,  1,  0,0,  0,0,  0,0,  0,0,0},
 {0,  0,  0,  1,1,  0,0,  0,0,  0,0,0}, (*This is the matrix.*)
 {0,  0,  0,  0,0,  1,1,  0,0,  0,0,0},
 {0,  0,  0,  0,0,  0,0,  1,1,  0,0,0},
 {0,  0,  0,  0,0,  0,0,  0,0,  1,1,1}}
```

All suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sL = Rest[Subsets@Range@3]
```

> ```
>  {{1}, {2}, {3}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}
> ```

You can also use [`SparseArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html) + [`Band`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Band.html):

```
ClearAll[f]
f = SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> List /@ Unitize@#] &;


f @ sL // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Alternatively, a combination of [`MapThread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html) + [`RotateRight`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RotateRight.html) + [`PadLeft`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PadLeft.html) + [`Accumulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Accumulate.html):

```
ClearAll[g]
g = Module[{cl = Accumulate[Length /@ #]}, 
  MapThread[RotateRight, {PadLeft[Unitize @ #, {Automatic, Last @ cl}], cl}]] &

g @ sL // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> same result

If you wish to use an integer as input, you can modify `f` as follows:

```
ClearAll[f2]
f2 = SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> List /@ Unitize @ Rest @ Subsets @ Range @ #] &;

f2 @ 3 // MatrixForm // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

You can modify `g` similarly.

Answer (score 5):

It isn't quite clear to me what is wanted, but the matrix in the OP can be generated readily, with a little help from an *undocumented* function:

```
With[{n = 3}, 
     SparseArray`SparseBlockMatrix[MapIndexed[Join[#2, #2] -> {#1} &,
                                              Unitize[Subsets[Range[n],
                                                              {1, ∞}]]]]] // MatrixForm
```

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! But the other answer provides several different ways of generating the desired matrix.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

n = 3;

L = Range[n];

SL = Subsets[L, {1, n}]

(* {{1}, {2}, {3}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}} *)
```

Freestanding commas do not make much sense. Perhaps you mean:

```
(mat = Module[{len = Length@SL},
    Array[ConstantArray[KroneckerDelta@##, Length[SL[[#2]]]] &, {len, 
      len}]]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: You could do `Flatten /@ mat` in that case I suppose.

Comment: @flinty - the spacing used in the desired output caused me to interpret the intent as desiring a 7x7 matrix with the elements given by the clusters formed by the spacing. Others interpreted the intent as a 7x12 matrix with the spacing having no significance. Presumably, I guessed wrong.

Comment: I'm afraid that  @flinty is right. It was my expression that misled you. Thank you very much for you answer.